# asp.net usercontrol odd behaviour

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a usercontrol that I am trying to use in a project.

If I do it like this (reference the sitemap in the control)

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="OS" Namespace="OS_Layouts" Assembly="OSControlLibrary, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0831306e55dc1c27" %>

<html><body>
<OS:OSmenu runat="server" ID="men1" SiteMap="siteMapDataSource1"  />
  <asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="false" SiteMapProvider="CombinedNavSiteMapProvider"
    ID="siteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
</body </html>
```

I get an odd error.

> Parser Error Message: Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource' from its string representation 'siteMapDataSource1' for the 'SiteMap' property.

If I do this it works fine. (add the sitemap in code during pageload)

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="OS" Namespace="OS_Layouts" Assembly="OSControlLibrary, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0831306e55dc1c27" %>
<script runat=server>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   men1.SiteMap = siteMapDataSource1;           
  }
</script>
<html><body>
<OS:OSmenu runat="server" ID="men1"  />
  <asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="false" siteMapProvider="CombinedNavSiteMapProvider" ID="siteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
</body> </html>
```

The only "clever" thing I am doing is using 'aspnet_compiler' and 'aspnet_merge' to create a .dll containing my usercontrols into a single dll I can use in other projects.

Have I misunderstood, or misconfigured something?

Thanks
EDIT: some further info.

So my aspx.cs looks like this
I always get "Fail!"

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class OSmenu : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{  

    public String SiteMapID { get; set; }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    if (SiteMapID == "") return;
       SiteMapDataSource foo = Page.FindControl(SiteMapID) as SiteMapDataSource;
        if (foo == null)
        {
            Response.Write("</br> fail!");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("/<br> ok!" + foo.UniqueID);
        }
    }



}
```

All this is slightly complicated by the fact the host page for the control is a sharepoint masterpage, and I cannot get debugging to work for the control, I can for the masterpage itself!

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your userconrol:

```
SiteMapDataSource ds = this.Page.FindControl(this.SiteMap) as SiteMapDataSource;
```